# hbase set memstore flush size to 0

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

In our hbase cluster memstore flush size is 128 mb. And to insert data to tables, we only use bulk load tool. Since bulk loading bypasses memstores, they are never used, so we want to minimize memstore flush size. But memstore flush size is used in many important calculations in hbase such that

```
region split size = Min (R^2 * “hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size”, “hbase.hregion.max.filesize”)
```

So setting memstore value smaller or "0" for example,  results in some other problems. 
What do you suggest us in that case. Setting memstore size to 128 holds some memory for tens of regions in region server and we want to get rid of it.

Comment: Here is the mail of dev@hbase.apache.org thanks to them:  If you are only bulk loading into HBase, then memstore flush size should 
not matter. You most likely you looking to lower the upper/global memstore 
limits.